# convert javascript code to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to change this javascript code to jQuery code, but for some reason when i'm targeting it normally with ID it's not working.

Javascript code:

```
scroll(xpos, ypos) { 
     document.getElementById('content_section').scrollTop=xpos;
}
```

jQuery code (i wrote):

```
scroll(xpos, ypos) { 
     $('#content_section').scrollTop(); 
}
```

what did i do wrong? and i need it to work on Internet Explorer.

for some answers i had, i tried to add scrollTop(xpos); and it didn't work still, put in mind IE issues.

Comment: scrollTop is the attribute of `content_section` element , right ? Try `$('#content_section').attr('scrollTop',xpos);`

Comment: scrollTop is not an attribute it's a jQuery function to scroll up

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#content_section').scrollTop(xpos);
```

because `scrollTop()` takes argument as it scroll target.

#### More detail

`.scrollTop()` without argument works like a getter method, that means

```
  $('#content_section').scrollTop(); // without argument
```

will give you current scroll position of `#content_section`.

But with argument it acts as a setter method that means

```
  $('#content_section').scrollTop(xpos); // with argument
```

will set the `#content_section` to the position you passed with argument.

#### According to your edit

```
function scroll(xpos, ypos) { 
     // you need to set argument xpos
     $('#content_section').scrollTop(xpos); 
}
```

May be you can try

```
function scroll() {
   $('#content_section').scrollTo({left: xpos, top: ypox}, 400);
}
```

Comment: the main function of this is function scroll(xpos, ypos) { $('#content_section').scrollTop(); } i tried to put the xpos inside and still not working

Comment: @HaiderGhaleb I try to explain detail, please check

Comment: i included the xpos inside the scrollTop function and still it didn't work, the main issue come's from IE

Comment: yes, it's exactly like your last edit code. i'm trying to figure out why it's not working on IE still

Comment: i tried to give xpos value 0 but also didn't work, also according to one of the answers i got i changed it to ypos and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the value of xpos in the jQuery method:

```
$('#content_section').scrollTop(ypos);
```

Comment: the main function of this is function scroll(xpos, ypos) { $('#content_section').scrollTop(); } i tried to put the xpos inside and still not working

Comment: And with `ypos` instead of `xpos`.

Answer (score 0):

i tested the following code in IE8 and works. please take a look.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll(xpos, ypos) {
        $('#content_section').scrollTop(ypos);
    }
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="scroll" onclick='scroll(0,0);' />
    <div id="content_section" style="overflow: auto; height: 60px; width: 60px;">
        a<br /> a<br /> a<br /> a<br /> a<br /> 
        a<br /> a<br /> a<br /> a<br /> a<br />  a<br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the main function of this is function scroll(xpos, ypos) { $('#content_section').scrollTop(); } i tried to put the xpos inside and still not working

Comment: @HaiderGhaleb, try using `ypos`. top-bottom are y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content_section').scrollTop();
```

That only returns the position of the element.
If you want to set it just use.

```
 $('#content_section').scrollTop(xpos);
```

xpos, of course, is the distance from the top of the page.

EDIT:

```
function scroll(xpos, ypos) { 
     // you need to set argument xpos
     $('#content_section').scrollTop(ypos); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    scroll(0,150)
});
```

Try that to see if it works. Notice that the element must be scrollable, i dont know what you are doing but of course if the whole page is smaller than the window then it will not scroll.

Comment: the main function of this is
function scroll(xpos, ypos) {
   $('#content_section').scrollTop();
}

i tried to put the xpos inside and still not working

Comment: xpos is the horizontal position, from left to right. You want vertical position, then use ypos. Try debugging with firebug to see if you are getting an error somewhere and to see if xpos and ypos are really set.

Comment: i added ypos but didn't work still, i tried to set the ypos = 0 but also didn't work.

Comment: also i can't firebug on IE :(

Comment: yeh i know but the project i'm working on it is IE based only :( :S

Comment: Added an example to see if it helps